# How do I select a template for a GroupBox based on the value of an object

Tags: .net, wpf, groupbox, contenttemplateselector

I want the contents of a group box to be selected by value, so how I do write the XAML to do this?

```
<GroupBox Header="Specific details"
    ContentTemplateSelector={StaticResource someSelector}>

...

</GroupBox>
```

The template selector will let me select which template to use, but what I can't figure is the syntax to associate this group box with a value in a variable somehow?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is to use a TabControl with no headers and let the SelectedIndex be set by the value.